# how to (minimally) adjust geom_text() labels to avoid overlap on stacked geom_col()

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I place non-overlapping direct labels on a stacked column chart?

`geom_text_repel()` is moving labels that don't need to be moved, creating readability problems.

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)


set.seed(23)
n <- 4
mu <- 4E6

sales <- tibble(
  year=as.factor(seq(2019, length.out=n)),
  A = rnorm(n=n, mean=mu, sd=mu/4),
  B = rnorm(n=n, mean=6*mu, sd=mu),
  C = rnorm(n=n, mean=mu/5, sd=mu/40),
  D = rnorm(n=n, mean=mu/10, sd=mu/40),
  E = rnorm(n=n, mean=4*mu, sd=mu)
) %>% pivot_longer(!year, names_to="product", values_to="sales")
  
p <- sales %>%
  group_by(year, product) %>%
  summarise(sales=sum(sales)) %>%
  mutate(pct_of_year_sales = sales/sum(sales),
         label=paste(
    scales::label_dollar(scale=1/1E6, suffix="M", accuracy=0.1)(sales),
    scales::label_percent(accuracy=0.1)(pct_of_year_sales),
    sep=", ")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=sales, fill=product, label=label)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_dollar(scale=1/1E6, suffix="M"),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05)))

p + geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)) +
  labs(title="geom_text()",
       subtitle="overlapping labels")
```

[image]

```r
p + geom_text_repel(position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
                    direction="y") + 
  labs(title="geom_text_repel()", 
       subtitle="text for series A moves needlessly")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I don’t think this is trivial, especially if you want to do this programmatically. my two cents worth: when I have a crowded visual like this, I take this as a sign to reconsider my visualisation. You’re not helping your reader a lot by trying to cram in as much information into a small space as possible. In this case, you seem to want to show the overall height, and also the percent. Why not showing a second graph that shows the percentages. Or, maybe try to make a nice table!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. valid points. The data and labels are just an example. The essence of the question points to an issue that would equally affect relatively simpler visuals.

Comment: Mac, I just saw you've rolled back my edit. I think the different title is more accurate and will help other people to find your question for similar problems. It's not about ALL the labels, thus the added "selected". You could also say "specific" or anything else, but the more precise the question is, the more useful it is for others

Comment: I rolled back the edit because the question seeks a programmatic, not selective answer--i.e. the developer shouldn't be choosing which specific labels should and should not move.

Answer (score 4):

I agree wholly with @tjebo's comment, sometimes adding so much text is not the best way. But sometimes it is mandated (out of our control), so I suggest addressing one of your complaints:

> `geom_text_repel()` is moving labels that don't need to be moved

We can use `geom_text` on most (filtering by percentage sales) and `geom_text_repel` on the few.

Normally, I'd use `data = ~ filter(., pct_of_year_sales <= 0.015))` (and `>` for the main), but the stacking is disrupted when the number and values of columns are disrupted. Instead, we can create two sets of labels where some are empty (`""` or `NA`) depending on their `pct_of_year_sales` value. This way, `geom_text_repel` gets to see all columns/values and will place them appropriately.

```r
dat <- sales %>%
  group_by(year, product) %>%
  summarise(sales=sum(sales), .groups="drop") %>%
  mutate(pct_of_year_sales = sales/sum(sales),
         label = paste(
           scales::label_dollar(scale=1/1E6, suffix="M", accuracy=0.1)(sales),
           scales::label_percent(accuracy=0.1)(pct_of_year_sales),
           sep=", ")) %>%
  mutate(
    label1 = if_else(pct_of_year_sales > 0.015, label, NA_character_),
    label2 = if_else(pct_of_year_sales <= 0.015, label, NA_character_)
  )

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=year, y=sales, fill=product, label=label1)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_dollar(scale=1/1E6, suffix="M"),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05))) +
  geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), na.rm = TRUE) +
  labs(title="geom_text()",
       subtitle="overlapping labels")
p
```

[image: ggplot2 without the repelling text]

```r
p +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
    min.segment.length = 0, force = 10,
    aes(label = label2),
    position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5), hjust = 0.25,
    direction="y", na.rm=TRUE)
```

[image: ggplot2 with repelling text added]

I added `hjust=` to shift them a little, also helping to clarify the segment lines (without `hjust`, they tend to connect with the commas, which is a visually-distracting artifact). You may want to play with `force=` or other segment-line aesthetics to break them out more clearly. (It would be feasible, for instance, to define `hjust` within the frame itself and assign that aesthetic within `aes(..)` instead, in order to control the horizontal justification per-year, for instance. Just a thought.)

Answer (score 4):

I think I like @r2evans answer better, as it utilizes the tools as they're meant to be used. I went a different route.

It's really never too early to start learning about the grid...

This uses the libraries `grid` and `gridExtra`.

First, I saved the plot to an object, and investigated where the labels were and what settings were applied (using `geom_text`, not `...repel`).

In `grid`, you can set the justification for each label. So I made the vertical justification of those values in `C` to 0 and in `D` to 1. This was enough in my plot pane... however, depending on the size of your graph, you may have to go to values that are further apart. Just remember that .5 is the middle, not 0.

See my code comments for a more in-depth explanation.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

pp <- p + geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)) +
  labs(title="geom_text()",
       subtitle="overlapping labels")
pg <- ggplotGrob(pp)        # create grid (gtable) of graph

# the labels in geom_text
pg$grobs[[6]]$children$GRID.text.246$label # use this to see the label order

# lbls top to btm then left to right
# get vjust to modify
gimme <- pg$grobs[[6]]$children$GRID.text.246$vjust

# which indices need to change (C and D labels)
ttxt <- seq(from = 3, by = 5, length.out = 4) # 5 labels in column
btxt <- seq(from = 4, by = 5, length.out = 4) # 4 columns

gimme[ttxt] <- 0 # set C to top of vspace
gimme[btxt] <- 1 # set D to bottom of vspace

# replace existing vjust
pg$grobs[[6]]$children$GRID.text.246$vjust <- gimme
```

You can view the plot with grid or change it back to a `ggplot` object. To change it back to a ggplot object you can either use `ggplotify::as.ggplot` or `ggpubr::as_ggplot`, they do the same thing.

```
plot.new()
grid.draw(pg)

# back to ggplot obj
ggpubr::as_ggplot(pg)
```

[image]

Comment: I salute your perseverance, pushing into the lower-level grid code! I tend to recommend _against_ it since it can be fragile (ggplot internal structure does change periodically), but it certainly is a strong approach to fixing some of the symptoms.